# ClojureScript: how to change CodeMirror reactively with Reagent

Tags: reactjs, clojurescript, codemirror, reagent

I'm trying to embed a CodeMirror in my webpage to edit several code snippets, one at a time.

To do this I:

- Have one Reagent atom `node-defs-atom` containing a map of the code snippets.
- Have another atom `node-history-atom` which contains the keys of the snippets being looked at
- Set the value of the CodeMirror to the value of the code map at the key.

Here's what doesn't work:

```
(defn editor [node-defs-atom node-history-atom]
  (reagent/create-class
    {:reagent-render (fn [] (do [:textarea
                     { :value (@node-defs-atom (last @node-history-atom))
                       :auto-complete "off"}]))
     :component-did-mount (editor-did-mount  node-defs-atom node-history-atom)
     }))

(defn editor-did-mount [node-defs-atom node-history-atom]
  (fn [this]
    (let [codemirror (.fromTextArea  js/CodeMirror
                                     (reagent/dom-node this)
                                     #js {:mode "clojure"
                                          :lineNumbers true})]

                            ...... )))
```

Changing `node-history-atom` with `reset!` doesn't do anything to the text in the CodeMirror. I'm really not sure what is going wrong.

If anyone could tell me where I should put the reference to `(@node-defs-atom (last @node-history-atom))` I'd be very grateful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try another way to deal with the CodeMirror editor

- Create a CM instance on an empty node

  ```
  (def cm (atom nil))

  (reset! cm (js/CodeMirror.
               (.createElement js/document "div")
               (clj->js {...})))
  ```
- Then your view will be a reagent class and `wrapper-id` is just an id of parent

  ```
  (reagent/create-class
    {:reagent-render         (fn [] @cm [:div {:id wrapper-id}])
     :component-did-update   update-comp
     :component-did-mount    update-comp})
  ```
- Create a function which appends CM to the dom node

  ```
  (defn update-comp [this]
    (when @cm
      (when-let [node (or (js/document.getElementById wrapper-id)
                          (reagent/dom-node this))]
        (.appendChild node (.getWrapperElement @cm))))
  ```

Comment: Thanks so much; I've managed to get this working, but I had to write a call to .setValue for every time I want to change the text, instead of it happening reactively based on the value of node-history-atom. Is it possible to make it happen this way?

Comment: You have to call .setValue every time you want to assign a new value because CodeMirror is stateful and you don't want to create it every time I suppose. But assigning can be done easily by `(reagent.ratom/run! (.setValue @text-atom))` macro.